# How to I find if certain nodes exist with a property value in CYPHER 2.3.2

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to do a validation to see if there are nodes exist with a certain relation ship. For eg  I have a request that has ["p1", "p2", "p3"] as a list of products, i would like to validate below cases and possible return a message.
Need some help in CYPHER.
IN my graph p1 and p2 are related as below, p3 is not connected to p1 and p2 at all.

### MATCH (p1:product)-[:REQUIRE]->(p2:product)

> 1. If the request has ["p1", "p2", "p3"] as a list i would like to return a message "You are good and move forward",
> 2. If the request has ["p1",  "p3"] as a list I would like to return a message "NO match, selecting P1 only is not enough, please select p2",
> 3. If the request has ["p4",  "p3"] as a list I would like to return a message "You are good and move forward",